# Convert to Deseq2 matrix

Tags: r

I am very new in using R. I would like to use de DESeq function in the DESeq2 package. I tried to convert my dataset from a text file to a DESeq matrix.

As an example:

```
datafile = "C:\\Users\\589016\\Desktop\\Test.csv"
countTable = read.delim(datafile, sep = ";", header = F)    
countTable
     V1  V2  V3   V4
b1  1,2   4  40   30
b2  3,2 3,4  50  3,1
b3    4 4,3  20 30,2
b4    5   3 3,2  3,4
b5  3,2 4,5   4  4,1
b6    0   5 2,1    3
b7  4,5   0 3,4  2,1
b8    3   0 0,1  2,1
b9    2 3,2 0,1    0
b10 0,4   0 0,1    1

ExpDesign = data.frame(row.names = colnames(countTable), condition = c("control", "control", "case", "case"))
ExpDesign
   condition
V1   control
V2   control
V3      case
V4      case
cds = DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = countTable, colData=ExpDesign$condition, design=~ExpDesign$condition)
```

But then I get the following message:

```
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")) : 
  attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions
```

What should I do?

Comment: Could you please format your code properly, and give some example data (e.g. the first 10 entries of your count table, and any further information to reproduce what you are trying to do). The `DESeq2` [vignette](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.pdf) is actually very clear on how to process a count table.

Comment: Your count table looks weird. Why is `(b1, V1)=1,2`? Is that supposed to be a decimal point, i.e. `1.2`? Counts are integer numbers, i.e. the number of mapped reads that associate with a particular feature. Can you double-check?